# Using buttons for my game in windowbuilder

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe, windowbuilder

I looked up earlier on Stack overflow how to use buttons with window builder in eclipse to where if you clicked it once it would do a line (or more) of code, then if you click again it would do a different line of code and so on (third,fourth,fifth click etc..)

I was wondering how you could make it so in Java, you could do this with the mouse Pressed event with the button. Here is my testing code (this code is not right at the moment that is acknowledged but I was wondering if you could use this for an example) Thank you, any help is appreciated.

This game is essentially picking from two or more given choices that lead you down a different path, and they enter it in the bottom textbox which is called Log and at the very top the text box is called console, when a user enters the answer into Log and clicks Send it prints the result of that answer into the console text box.

[updated info part]
Hello, I am trying to make a game in which the user gets a question on the top box which is called "console" and they enter the answer in the bottom box "Log" and then press send to move on to the next part. After that I want it to do the same thing, Instead of down below (my updated code), of making different buttons and making the one non-visible so they are able to click the next one, I want it to just be one button that they click and each time it processes the different lines of code i.e if the question in box console says do you want a sword or bow, and the user chooses bow and enters it into the log box and hits send i want it to say ok, how much gold do you need. User enters the amount and hits send. so on and so forth. Thank you again for any help you may give.

```
package Game;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Random;
public class Swendiver {

    private JFrame frmSwendiver;
    private JTextField console;
    private JTextField Log;
    private JTextField Weapon;
    private JTextField Arrows;
    private JTextField next;
    private JTextField Class;
    private JTextField Coin;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Swendiver window = new Swendiver();
                    window.frmSwendiver.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Swendiver() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmSwendiver = new JFrame();
        frmSwendiver.setTitle("Swendiver 1.0");
        frmSwendiver.setAutoRequestFocus(false);
        frmSwendiver.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frmSwendiver.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frmSwendiver.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        console = new JTextField();
        console.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 44);
        console.setEditable(false);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(console);
        console.setColumns(10);

        Log = new JTextField();
        Log.setBounds(0, 241, 434, 20);
        Log.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                // KeyEvent.getKeyCode(VK_ENTE-R);
            }
        });
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(Log);
        Log.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblThankYouFor = new JLabel("Health : 100%");
        lblThankYouFor.setBackground(new Color(50, 205, 50));
        lblThankYouFor.setBounds(165, 165, 100, 27);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(lblThankYouFor);
        console.setText("Press The enter button to start Swendiver");
        JButton Send = new JButton("Enter");
        Send.setBounds(345, 41, 89, 200);
        Send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            }
        });
        Send.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                boolean isClicked = true;
                if (isClicked == true) {
                    isClicked = false;

                    lblThankYouFor.setName("Health: 75%");
                    console.setText("[Hermin] Welcome. Ready for your adventure? (Click Enter)");
                    Send.setVisible(false);
                }
            }

        @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                Log.setText("");
                ArrayList<String> weapon = new ArrayList<String>();
                console.setText("Ok, choose your weapon. <SWORD>||<BOW>");
                // Log.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("SWORD")
                // console.setText("Good choice.");
                Log.setText("");
                weapon.add("Sword");
                if (weapon.get(0).equalsIgnoreCase("Sword")) {
                    console.setText("[Hermin] A sword? I see. Good choice...");
                    next.setText("This box is used for Instructions/Actions");
                }
            }
        });

        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(Send);

        JLabel lblWeapon = new JLabel("Weapon:");
        lblWeapon.setBounds(266, 87, 56, 14);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(lblWeapon);
        JButton button3 = new JButton("Enter");
        button3.setBounds(345, 41, 89, 200);
        Weapon = new JTextField();
        Weapon.setBounds(249, 101, 86, 20);
        Weapon.setEditable(false);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(Weapon);
        Weapon.setColumns(10);

        JButton Enter = new JButton("Enter");
        Enter.setBounds(345, 41, 89, 200);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(Enter);


        JLabel lblArrows = new JLabel("Arrows:");
        lblArrows.setEnabled(false);
        lblArrows.setBounds(165, 87, 46, 14);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(lblArrows);

        Arrows = new JTextField();
        Arrows.setEnabled(false);
        Arrows.setBounds(155, 101, 68, 20);
        Arrows.setEditable(false);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(Arrows);
        Arrows.setColumns(10);
            Random attack = new Random();
        next = new JTextField();
        next.setBounds(0, 41, 239, 27);
        next.setEditable(false);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(next);
        next.setColumns(10);
        boolean attacksituation = false;
        JButton Attack = new JButton("Attack");
        Attack.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if(attacksituation == true) {
                next.setText(Integer.toString(attack.nextInt(5)));
                Attack.setEnabled(false);
                Attack.setEnabled(true);
                }
                }
        });
        Attack.setBounds(0, 68, 89, 173);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(Attack);

        JLabel lblClass = new JLabel("Class:");
        lblClass.setBounds(276, 47, 46, 14);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(lblClass);

        Class = new JTextField();
        Class.setEditable(false);
        Class.setBounds(249, 61, 86, 20);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(Class);
        Class.setColumns(10);

        Coin = new JTextField();
        Coin.setText("78");
        Coin.setEditable(false);
        Coin.setBounds(125, 221, 86, 20);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(Coin);
        Coin.setColumns(10);
        next.setText("");
        JLabel lblCoin = new JLabel("Coin:");
        lblCoin.setBounds(99, 224, 46, 14);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(lblCoin);
        Enter.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText("[Hermin]Choose your class <Warrior> or <Archer>");
                if (Log.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Warrior")) {
                    console.setText("[Hermin]A Swordsman.. I see. Good choice.");
                    Weapon.setText("Sword");
                    next.setEnabled(true);
                    next.setText("Click Enter to continue");
                    Log.setText("");
                    Class.setText("Warrior");
                    Enter.setVisible(false);
                }
                if (Log.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Archer")) {
                    console.setText("[Hermin]An Archer.. Interesting. Here are your Items.");
                    Weapon.setText("Long-Bow");
                    Arrows.setText("19");
                    next.setEnabled(true);
                    next.setText("Click Enter to continue");
                    Log.setText("");
                    Class.setText("Archer");
                    lblArrows.setEnabled(true);
                    Arrows.setEnabled(true);
                    Enter.setVisible(false);

                }
                if(Log.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("/secretcommand")) {
                    Coin.setText(Integer.toString(300));
                    next.setText("222 Coin Aquired");
                    next.setEnabled(true);
                    Log.setText("");
                    next.setText("Click Enter to continue!");
                    Enter.setVisible(false);
                }

            }

        });

        button3.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                console.setText("[Hermin] Great. Welcome then. Head into SheildsTown to collect some items."); 
                next.setText("/EquipArmor to get geared and go.");
                if(Log.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("/EquipArmor")){
                    next.setText("You leave the armory.");
                    console.setText("");
                    Log.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(button3);

    }
}
```

Comment: See [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: You should also avoid using `KeyListener` with text components, instead, preferring the use of `ActionListener`. See [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) for more details

Comment: Please explain clearly what you are trying to do and why it doesn't work. Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), if your question is about buttons then make the code about it too, it looks very bloated.